# PHP 5.2, mysqli sporaically gives "Can't connect to MySQL server" error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've inherited an older php system with a problem I'm stumped on how to debug.  Basically, the pages are littered with lines like...

```
mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB) or trigger_error(mysqli_connect_error());
```

...and it works 99% of the time.  But about every 200 visits or so, I'll get an alert that the above error occurred.

The system has a custom error handler that essentially just grabs the error and prints out everything about the session and error so I have the line number of the offending file along with any GET and POST params.  The problem is, there isn't anything off with the data that I see.  I can't recreate it.

So really I'm looking for ideas on what it could be that's causing this, and/or what I could do to diagnose this problem.  I'm stumped.

Comment: Is there anything in the server logs? It is a relatively common error for example that the maximum connection limit is reached and new connections are not allowed.

Comment: That's the awesome part of this system.  It has a bizarre custom logging setup that makes debugging remarkably hard.  In short, no.  Nothing interesting in the logs.  The only logs it keeps are access logs and it emails the errors to dev.

Comment: I meant previously the mysql server logs. (/var/log/mysql or something similar) Anyway if you don't have logs, you should enable logging anyway.

Comment: I don't know if this is because of the custom error handler (seems unlikely) but the mysql error logs are empty.  The "normal" logs are full of non error transactions, but nothing matches up with the error I'm seeing.

Comment: You can tune the logging in the /etc/mysql/ directory for mysql. There should be something on mysql side if the server refuses the clients. Otherwise more logging on (mysql) client side could also help.

Comment: Turned on the general logging, but didn't see anything that corresponded to an connection error.